# Создать iso своей системы Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, образ, iso-образ

Есть система, на которой установлено множество пакетов и произведено множество настроек. Как создать iso образ этой системы сохраняя все настройки? Пробовал `remastersys`, но никак не могу установить ее ни с репозиториев, ни с исходников. Вариант подобный "Suse Studio" для Ubuntu тоже рассматривается **UPD:**   Для решения задачи подошла программа "relinux"

Comment: А какова цель? Это нужно для сохранения, восстановления системы или для установки новой системы?

Comment: Нужно расклонировать систему на разные компьютеры, очень много настроек, чтобы производить установку "с нуля"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для клонирования Linux системы можно воспользоваться средствами [MondoRescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/docs/mondorescue-howto.html). Они позволяют сохранить работающую систему на диск и восстановить систему с диска.